# Combine Multiple JSON Array Objects by key in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to combine the following json arrays into one(targetArray) by key.

jsonArray[0] : [ {key:A01, data:a}, {key:A02, data:b}, {key:A03, data:c} ]

jsonArray[1] : [ {key:A01, data:o}, {key:A02, data:p}, {key:A03, data:q} ]

jsonArray[2] : [ {key:A01, data:s},  {key:A02, data:t}, {key:A03, data:u} ]

jsonArray[N] ...

↓

**targetJsonArray : [ {key:A01, data:a|o|s}, {key:A02, data:b|p|t}, {key:A03, data:c|q|u} ...]**

The final result is of type jsonArray, the KEY value is fixed and the data value needs to be added. Can I combine them together by key ? Please give advice or sample code :)

```
    String strArr1 = "{message:[ {key:A01, data:a}, {key:A02, data:b}, {key:A03, data:c} ]}"; 
    String strArr2 = "{message:[ {key:A01, data:o}, {key:A02, data:p}, {key:A03, data:q} ]}";
    String strArr3 = "{message:[ {key:A01, data:s}, {key:A02, data:t}, {key:A03, data:u} ]}";

    String[] arraySrcObjMsg = {strArr1,strArr2,strArr3};

    JSONArray jsonTargetArray = new JSONArray();

    for(int i=0; i<arraySrcObjMsg.length; i++) {

        String srcMsg = arraySrcObjMsg[i];
        JSONObject jsonSrcObj = new JSONObject(srcMsg);
        JSONArray jsonSrcArray = jsonSrcObj.getJSONArray("message");

        for(int j=0; j<jsonSrcArray.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject jsonSubItem = jsonSrcArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String key = jsonSubItem.getString("key");
            String data = jsonSubItem.getString("data");

            System.out.println("key : " + key);
            System.out.println("data : " + data);

            //Do Something make combine
            //jsonTargetArray.put(key, data=data+"|")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the effort you've done by writing some code to solve this problem?

Comment: I attatched my code, I did'n make it yet. please see it and help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of combine into Array why don't try using HashMap <String,<List<String >>. 
 Another option is 
 Multimap<String, String> params = ArrayListMultimap.create();

Both this is easy and useful to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the direct answer. But this can guide you how you can think of the code that you need to write.

You need to think your problem as List of Lists. `List<List<Student>>`. I just assumed that your one object as a `Student`. (`{key:A01, data:s}`). Then you can achieve what you need like below.

```
    Student s1 = new Student("1234", "steve", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-01"), LocalDate.parse("2019-09-10");
    Student s2 = new Student("4321", "George", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-01"), LocalDate.parse("2019-09-10");
    Student[] arr1 = {s1};
    Student[] arr2 = {s2};

    Map<String, List<Student>> result = Arrays.asList(arr1, arr2)
            .stream()
            .flatMap(arr -> Arrays.asList(arr).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added sample code, can I ask you example code based on my sample code?